# How to correctly synchronize access to the instance variable in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to synchronize access to the instance variable of type BOOL in Objective-C. Can I use atomic for the non-properties data members or should I use `@synchronized` in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're not declaring a property, you can't use `atomic`, and if you are, you can only use `@synchronized` if you're implementing the accessors yourself. Can you be more clear about the situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use a property, the most performant way to synchronize access to a `BOOL` is just to use a memory barrier.

Before each read of the variable, call `__sync_synchronize();`. After each write, call `__sync_synchronize();` too. This is much faster than `@synchronized`, but for a `BOOL`, `short` or `int` it is just as safe. (On 64-bit platforms this also works for 64-bit integers. Don't use this approach with object pointers though!)

Example code:

```
__sync_synchronize();
if(_myFlag) {
    showUserAlert(@"my flag is set!!! OMG!");
}
//...
if(self.userWantsFlags) {
    _myFlag = YES;
    __sync_synchronize();
}
```

You can of course also encapsulate this behaviour by just defining an `atomic` property, and using this instead of the instance variable...

See also: [more info on atomic builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html)

Comment: What is the difference between __sync_synchronize and @synchronized?

Comment: One is a memory barrier, the other is a mutex. A mutex is much more than a memory barrier, and not needed in this case. You may want to just google "memory barrier" and "mutex" @FrozenHeart

Comment: @synchronized works. Everybody knows what it does, and that it works. Feel free to save a few nanoseconds by using some different and probably undocumented function; anyone maintaining or debugging your code will waste hours of time checking what exactly __sync_synchronize does.

Comment: @gnasher729 `__sync_synchronize()` isn't exactly undocumented ;) it's a memory barrier, which is the first thing you learn when you learn about lock-free-thread-safe-programming. and its really 10 times or more faster than `@synchronized`. Chances are that the OP cares about performance this much, because otherwise he would probably not have asked the question.